# Is there way to make a Schema Generic in Mongo Db?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying a side project and I want to generate Different Schemas which there are dependent on user request body fields, is there a way to do it with MongoDb?
The way I am thinking is to try to make in some way Generic MongoDb schemas. Currently my thought is very abstract so i am seeking help here for that.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I suggest reading up on these 2 official blog posts by MongoDB. [Attribute Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern), [Polymorphic Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/polymorphic-pattern/)

Comment: Thanks Ramit i have read those blog posts and i think they guide me on a correct path.